# Why replacing strings from dictionary produce empty file

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace some strings with other strings in a text file,
but the code produce empty file (file size is 0)

what am I missing ?

```
emotion_list = {":-)" : "happy-similey", \
                ":-(": "sad-similey"}

for line in fileinput.input(file_name, inplace=True):
    if not line:
        continue
    for f_key, f_value in emotion_list.items():
        if f_key in line:
            line = line.replace(f_key, f_value)
```

Comment: show the content of `file_name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missing the `print` statement to send replaced line to your file:

```py
for line in fileinput.input(file_name, inplace=True):

    if not line:
        continue
    for f_key, f_value in emotion_list.items():
        if f_key in line:
            line = line.replace(f_key, f_value)

    print(line, end="") # print without newline
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are maching file line with word.So split line by spaces to get words (If you do match word in a entire line then you have to give the no.of occurences you want to replace and no of occurences is dynamic.You don't how much occurences would be there in file in a real scenarios)

```
emotion_list = {":-)" : "happy-similey", \
                ":-(": "sad-similey"}


file="I am not really :-) but I am not :-( too "

for line in file.split(): 
    for f_key, f_value in emotion_list.items():
        if f_key == line:            
            file=file.replace(line, f_value,1)

print(file)
```

output

```
I am not really happy-similey but I am not sad-similey too
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the problem you are facing:

```
lst = ["abc", "acd", "ade"]

for x in lst:
  x = x.replace("a", "x")

print(lst) # ["abc", "acd", "ade"]
```

Instead, you should replace the ith element of the list:

```
lst = ["abc", "acd", "ade"]

for i, x in enumerate(lst):
  lst[i] = x.replace("a", "x")

print(lst) # ['xbc', 'xcd', 'xde']
```

This is happening because strings are *immutable* in Python!